# SQLITE: How do I sort a String column containing values 1-99 and letters a-z, with numbers first then letters

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sorting

I want a sort order for a string column like the following (numbers first, letters last):

```
1
2
...
10
11
...
A
B
C
...
```

Here's my current query

```
SELECT * FROM PAGES_VIEW ORDER BY chapterTitle
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following ordering (10 before 2)

```
1
10
2
20
...
A
B
...
```

How do I achieve my desired order?

*EDIT*: removed my CAST as integer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `case` statement to get the desired `order`ing.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/a2bbb/1)

```
select * from pages_view 
order by (case when cast(chaptertitle as integer) = chaptertitle then 1
         else 0 end) desc, cast(chaptertitle as integer), chaptertitle
```

Comment: Probably want to have a second sort term of `chaptertitle` at the end, so it first sorts by the type (0 or 1 per your case statement) THEN by the actual text.

Comment: @jklemmack.. the `else` part handles the text part.

Comment: Really you're just sorting "0" and "1".  If the data doesn't happen to be in order otherwise, the sort is wrong.  Tweak your fiddle with the following data.  While your answer works for the explicit question, it makes some assumptions, and I don't want others to be mislead later on:

insert into t values('Q'),('R'),('50'),('2'),('10'),('C'),('D'),('25'),('F'),('100')

Comment: @jklemmack.. i realized my mistake. corrected it now.

Comment: this doesn't work, if the table created with "TEXT" field. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2a12ad/2